# How to add dynamic text on date cell in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to know how to add dynamic text to specific date in inline jquery [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline),
Here is what I tried but this is **not for inline datepicker**

```js
$(function () { 
             $("#datepicker").datepicker();
             $("#datepicker").focus(function () { 
                 
                 $(".ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default").each(function () { 
                     var year = $(".ui-datepicker-year").first().html()
                     if ($(".ui-datepicker-month").first().html() == "June" && $(this).html() == "20")
                     { 
                         $(this).html("Text 1");
                     }
                     if ($(".ui-datepicker-month").first().html() == "June" && $(this).html() == "21") 
                     { 
                         $(this).html("Text 2");
                     }

                 });
             }); 
         });
```

I searched on web, doesnt got any positive response. I am new in jquery, so a sample code or basic idea are welcome.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on exactly what you are wanting to achieve? "adding dynamic text to a specific date" doesn't really mean anything. Do you want the text to show up in the little cell of the date? Do you want the text to show up when you click on the date?

Comment: @Panomosh 1) I have booking website ,in admin panel i want show the pending booking and approved booking for example: 20 june , Pending. 21 june, Approved etc. 2) Yes i want the text to show up in the little cell of the datepicker 3) No, It should show up when page is loaded.

Comment: How will the text display in the cell? The cell is only 25px at most. You could probably get 2 characters in there. Screenshot the Datpicker element and edit it in MSPaint to show us what you would like to achieve.

Comment: By using css we can inrease the width and height of the each cells. So we can add the text in each cell.